# Who does a university answer to if their staff and academic advisors make mistakes that cost you time and money?

Tags: advisor

I am in a situation where my university has made countless mistakes with their new online program.  Professors are "no-shows", do not instruct at all, and advisors have incorrectly registered me in their new program which has now delayed my graduation date and has cost me money.  Who do you report a university to that repeatedly makes so many mistakes but has no problem taking your money?

Comment: Ombuds Office, student union representative, an administrator (department chair or dean) of the unit where the mistakes were made would all be reasonable options. If the institution is sufficiently poorly run and unresponsive (which sadly sounds like it may be the case here), unfortunately the only option likely to yield any sort of real results is hiring a lawyer and filing a lawsuit.

Answer (score 1):

Every University has a Grievances Redressal Mechanism. Usually, it is a form online that you fill where different types of grievances/reports/complaints are handled by different committees/bodies. e.g. Sexual harassment, Discrimination based on race, etc

Information on how to ask for support or file a complaint and the escalation process is usually detailed in the Student Handbook and on the University Website.

Try having a look at your handbook or search online. And if it is no secret, you can let us know the University name, and somebody here might be able to help locate the right office you can approach for help.

Edit: Although writing directly to the Provost/Vice Chancellor/President, etc or airing your grievance online on social media is frowned upon without exhausting established avenues of help, since you mentioned 'online program', you might want to try to write a polite email asking for this precise information to your program coordinator.

Comment: "Every University has [...]" is quite a strong statement given the variability of university structures and customs around the world.

Comment: I was referring to the universality of complaint resolution mechanisms. I get what you are hinting at, but It was not a generalisation and should not be read as one.